# Astropy complaining about Numpy version

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

I just updated Astropy to version 3.1.2.  Now I'm trying to run a (previously working) Python 3 script that uses it, and it's failing with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./body-local.py", line 3, in <module>
    from astropy.time import Time
  File "/home/jimc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astropy/__init__.py", line 121, in <module>
    _check_numpy()
  File "/home/jimc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astropy/__init__.py", line 115, in _check_numpy
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Numpy version 1.13.0 or later must be installed to use Astropy
```

My installed Numpy version is 1.16.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bad Numpy installation.  The solution was to repeatedly uninstall Numpy, as regular user and root, until no more installations were found, then reinstall:

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
sudo pip3 uninstall numpy
```

^ Until no more remain, then:

```
sudo pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: It's probably checking the package metadata (e.g. `pkg_resources.get_distribution('numpy').version`, as opposed to say `import numpy; numpy.__version__`. The former comes from the `numpy-<version>.egg-info` (or `.dist-info`). Normally if you manage packages with pip it will manage these correctly as well. But if you go around pip or do something else unusual (which isn't that uncommon in user-managed site-packages) you can wind up with extra, invalid `.egg-info` directories lying around. You can just delete these manually too if you're sure what the right version is.