# Numpy version issue when using astropy

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

I am currentling trying to use a package I installed (stsynphot), but I have the following error when typing `import stsynphot as stsyn`

`ImportError: Numpy version 1.9.0 or later must be installed to use Astropy`

I was curious so just to try, I tried `import astropy` and of course had the same error.

Nevertheless, I do have numpy 1.14 installed, I have tried all the upgrade and reinstall procedures but I still have the issue.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: What does your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable contain?  When you run `which pip` what does it return?  What about `python -c 'import numpy; print(numpy)'` and `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`?

Comment: From your other comments below it looks like you might have a broken build of Numpy in your `~/.local/` directory.  Try removing that first.   You might also consider using `conda`/`anaconda` to manage your scientific Python dependencies.

Comment: I would also add that current versions of Astropy and stsynphot are Python 3.5 and up only, and it looks like you are trying to install into a Python 2.7 installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083379/astropy-complaining-about-numpy-version

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install --user astropy[all]
```

and for the stsynphot package follow these steps: https://stsynphot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: They should run `pip install --user` in this case as they are trying to install into `~/.local`.  They should also confirm they are using the correct `python`.  Current releases of Astropy and stsynphot are Python 3-only.